# Bash Shell - Script para obter URL's com palavra escolhida pelo utilizador

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

Boa noite,
Tenho uma duvida em relação a um script em bash shell que irá devolver os URL's presentes numa pagina do reddit, ou seja, num subreddit. O que consegui até agora foi devolver os URL's que estão numa página inserido no código e queria que quando executasse o programa o utilizador pudesse escrever uma palavra e o script iria buscar os URL's com essa palavra em comum. Este é o código que tenho ate agora:

```
" wget -qO- https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/ |grep -Eo "(http)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" | sort | uniq "
```

Comment: Você pode usar o read para capturar o termo e depois usar um grep para filtrar

`#!/bin/bash

read -p "Informe um termo: " term;

wget -qO- https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/ |grep -Eo "(http)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" | grep $term | sort | uniq`

Comment: Experimentei assim e depois de inserir o termo a pesquisar o programa acaba e não faz nada. Mas o que queria mesmo era que quando estivesse na linha de comandos e fizesse ./reddit.sh, á frente disso escrevesse a palavra de pesquisa por exemplo ./reddit.sh linux

Comment: É este o resultado que pretendo...                                                               "$ ./reddit.sh linux" e quando desse enter apareciam os URL's http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3001?                                 http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994&amp;_utm_source=1-2-2                                              http://www.shashlik.io/news/2016/02/18/shashlik-0-9-0-kubuntu-package/

Comment: Para utilizar argumentos basta usar ** $1 ** para capturar o primeiro termo , ** $2 ** para capturar o segundo termos (se houver) e assim por diante. Ou seja, basta substituir o read por `term=$1`

Comment: Continua a não dar, deve estar algo errado, o codigo agora está assim:                                      #!/bin/bash term=$1 wget -qO- https://www.reddit.com |grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" | grep $term | sort | uniq